# Since magical creatures in Harry Potter have certain body parts that imbue magical properties, can wizards have the same?

Tags: harry-potter

For example, Dragon's Blood has 12 uses (Albus Dumbledore found all of them).

Phoenix Tail Feather, Unicorn Tail Hair, Dragon Heartstring, Veela Hair, Rougarou Hair, Thestral Tail Hair, etc... are used for wand cores.

Phoenix tears have magical healing properties.

Do wizard and witches body parts have some magical properties too? Since they're magical?

Comment: Hair of a Veila comes to mind, but nothing else. Except for soul, if you're willing to stretch.

Comment: Blood, most probably. Voldemort does use it in GoF -- and  Dumbledore in HBP.

Comment: @Gallifreyan, hair is used in Polyjuice.

Comment: I would say that research into the possible magical properties of witch/wizard body parts has been extremely limited - what witch/wizard would give up the body part for the research? ;-)

Comment: Magic is genetic... so do the genes count as a body part? Witches and Wizards are wholly magical in a sense, they can create magic...

Comment: I tried to google the answer to this question... I'm not entirely too happy with what Google had to show me *ahem*

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To *Harry Potter's magical body parts*?

Comment: •childhood ruined•

Answer (score 4):

### **Yes, Wizards' flesh can revive a horcrux-spirit into a full body:**

Here is the one example from the books:

> And now Wormtail was whimpering. He pulled a long, thin,
>   shining silver dagger from inside his cloak. His voice broke into
>   petrified sobs.
>   “Flesh — of the servant — w-willingly given — you will —
>   revive — your master.”
>   He stretched his right hand out in front of him — the hand
>   with the missing finger. He gripped the dagger very tightly in his
>   left hand and swung it upward.
>   Harry realized what Wormtail was about to do a second before it 
>   happened — he closed his eyes as tightly as he could, but he could
>   not block the scream that pierced the night, that went through
>   Harry as though he had been stabbed with the dagger too. He
>   heard something fall to the ground, heard Wormtail’s anguished
>   panting, then a sickening splash, as something was dropped into
>   the cauldron.

Answer (score -2):

Due to ethical reasons, research discovering magical usage of wizard's body parts should be extremely limited, but there's no reason to believe that wizard's body parts can't have magical properties. We have few follow ups:

- A wizard's hair is used in Polyjuice Potion. Means, hair carries all of the information about a wizard, even his haircut style.
- A wizard's blood is used to bypass sacrificial love protection. Means, a wizard's blood is his identity card for abstract magical entities.